# Segmentation fault with fopen

Tags: c

I have `price.dat` in which a fruit name and the price are written a line.

```
apple 100
orange 50
banana 30
strawberry 530
```

Now I'd like to read this file, calculate the sum and write the sum to another file `total_price.txt`. But the code below doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("../price.dat", "r"); //(*0)This is allowed.

    char *name;
    int price = 0;
    int total = 0;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        ;
    } else {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s%d", name, &price) == 2) {
            printf("%s costs %d yen.\n", name, price);
            total += price;
        }

        puts("----------");
        printf("total: %d(yen)\n", total);

        FILE *fp2;
        //fp2 = fopen("../total_price.txt", "w"); //(*1)This is now allowed.
        //fopen("../total_price.txt", "w"); //(*2)This is allowed.
        //fclose(fp2);

        fclose(fp);
    }

}
```

Could anyone tell me the reason? I don't understand why (*0) is allowed but (*1) is not allowed. Because (*2) is allowed, I think substitution with `=` operator causes the problem.

Error message:

```
/bin/bash: line 1:  5260 Segmentation fault      "/home/***/***".out
shell returned 139
```

Environment:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Can you add the error message please ?

Comment: @JosephBudin I added the error message.

Comment: @user3121023 Rewriting `char *name` as `char name[100]` makes the code work properly. But why? `name` isn't related to `fp2 =`, is it?

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you. I understand well now. And I'll keep in mind that I had better add the (length-1) right before 's' like `%99s`. Also I'll read the manual of other functions you told me.